# How to insert a string into an array of text inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, input

Basically, I have a large string that i am splitting, then splitting again.

I then need to use the smallest split array to place its elements into text inputs on my page.

**This is my Javascript**

```
var splitquestions = vals[2].split('\n');

              //Loop to go through all current questions
              for (var i = 0; i < splitquestions.length - 1; i++) 
              {
                  //trigger a question add where a single question data can be added into
                  $( "#add" ).trigger('click');

                  //split current question into separate items
                  var s = splitquestions[i].split(',');

                  //Loop to go over all sections in a question
                  var count = 0;
                  for(var j = 0; j < s.length; j++)
                  {
                      count = count + 1;
                      var qs = document.getElementById('questions[' + j +'][' + count + ']').value;

                      qs = s[j];

                  }

              }
```

There will be many questions on the page, depending how many the user will like to add. Each new question block will consist of a question, 3 wrong answers, and 1 correct answer.

The part that is going wrong is within the last loop. This is where I need to grab each individual element within the 's' array, and place it within each text input.

This is how the raw data is displayed before it is split by the 'splitquestions' variable:

```
question1,incorrect-answer1,incorrect-answer2,incorrect-answer3,correct-answer
question2,incorrect-answer1,incorrect-answer2,incorrect-answer3,correct-answer
question3,incorrect-answer1,incorrect-answer2,incorrect-answer3,correct-answer
```

As you can see from above, each question is separated by a line-break, being \n, then each individual part is comma separated.

Each question input has a multidimensional variable assigned to its ID. For example, using the data above, the first line of data, along with the very first element (being question1) would be question[1][1]. Another example would be 'incorrect-answer1' on the third line of data, which would be question[3][2]. The first number is the question number, and the second number is the element number.

I hope that I've explained this well enough, since I am a little confused on how to explain it myself since I am new to multidimensional arrays and loops inside loops. So please, if you need any additional information, just post a comment and I'll do my best.

**If needed**, this is the function that creates the question elements dynamically:

```
function dynamicForm () {

    //set a counter
    var i = $('.dynamic-input#form-step2').length + 1;
    //alert(i);
    //add input
    $('a#add').click(function () {
        $('<table><tr><td><p><span class="left"><input type="text" class="dynamic-input" name="questions[' +i +'][1]" id="' + i + '" placeholder="Question" /></span>' + '<span class="right"><input type="text" class="dynamic-input" name="questions[' +i +'][2]" id="' + i + '" placeholder="Distraction 1" /><br /><input type="text" class="dynamic-input" name="questions[' +i +'][3]" id="' + i + '" placeholder="Distraction 2" /><br /><input type="text" class="dynamic-input" name="questions[' +i +'][4]" id="' + i + '" placeholder="Distraction 3" /><br /><input type="text" class="dynamic-input" name="questions[' +i +'][5]" id="' + i + '" placeholder="Correct Answer" /><br /><a href="#">Remove</a></span></p></td></tr></table>').fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#extender');
        i++;

        $("a:contains('Remove')").click(function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });

        return false;
    });


    //fadeout selected item and remove
    $("#form-step2.dynamic-input").on('click', 'a', function () {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function () {
            $(this).empty();
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can u simulate the same on a Jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @dreamweiver - I think that would be far to difficult since there are many other functions that are involved

Comment: I guess you can just include the relevant functions,which defines the scope of your prob

Comment: @dreamweiver - I'll give it my best and get back to you in a second

Comment: @dreamweiver - Sorry mate, tried to get it working although it won't work without many other of my functions and other scripts.
Basically, I just need to find out why the contents of my last loop isn't working.

Comment: @fizzix Perhaps you mean this? `var qs = document.getElementById('questions[' + j +'][' + count + ']');` and then `qs.value = s[j];`, or simply `document.getElementById('questions[' + j +'][' + count + ']').value = s[j];` Because as far as I can tell, the last lines makes no sense to me because you are gathering the value of the input and then replace the value of the variable, not the input itself.

Comment: @plalx - Sorry mate, still refusing to work :(

Comment: @fizzix, Do you get any errors in the console? Does it enter your last loop? Did you check if it correctly gets a reference to your inputs for each iterations? You can use your browser's debugging tool to do this by putting some break points, or simply putting some `console.log` lines in your code. E.g. `console.log(qs);`

Comment: @plalx - This is the error showing - 'TypeError: qs is null --- qs.value = s[j];'

Comment: I will try and step through the loop now and let you know what happens

Comment: It steps through all loops perfectly. Although, the main error is that 'qs' is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further discussions with the OP, we fixed the code ended up being what's below. Basically, his input numbers are starting at index 1 instead of 0, so that was one of the issues. He was also trying to select by `id` while the inputs in question only had a `name` attribute.

```
//Loop to go over all sections in a question
for (var j = 1, len = s.length; j <= len; j++) { 
    $('input[name="questions[' + (i + 1) + '][' + j + ']"]').val(s[j - 1]); 
}
```